# What is the reasonable frequency of ScanCallback when using Android BLE ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, bluetooth-lowenergy

I hope to have real time response to ble devices which are broadcasting. Since Android Lollipop (SDK 21), there is new API and I did the test on

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.html
>   ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY
>
> > Scan using highest duty cycle. It's recommended to only use this mode when the application is running in the foreground.

Here is the code start ble scan

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
    ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build();
    bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, scanSettings, scanCallback );
}
```

It simply measures frame rate in the ScanCallback()

```
private MeasureFps measureFps = new MeasureFps(6);
private final ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        measureFps.AddRecord(true);
    }
};
```

The source code of MeasureFps is [here](https://gist.github.com/JackFan-Z/ed1f30bd4ef3efcaada0d472d0549436).

I run the test on Nexus 5X, which is Android Marshmallow.
The results are mostly over 300 ms, and could be 2 seconds.
Are these expected?
It would be great if they are stably under 300 ms.

```
22:18:34.203  I/MeasureFps: Average frame time = 2237.4 ms
22:18:36.792  I/MeasureFps: Average frame time = 485.6 ms
22:18:40.481  I/MeasureFps: Average frame time = 724.0 ms
22:18:43.467  I/MeasureFps: Average frame time = 343.8 ms
22:18:44.904  I/MeasureFps: Average frame time = 251.8 ms
22:18:47.238  I/MeasureFps: Average frame time = 427.8 ms
22:18:48.491  I/MeasureFps: Average frame time = 73.4 ms
22:18:56.139  I/MeasureFps: Average frame time = 288.6 ms
22:18:57.411  I/MeasureFps: Average frame time = 237.4 ms
22:18:58.393  I/MeasureFps: Average frame time = 182.2 ms
22:18:59.953  I/MeasureFps: Average frame time = 310.4 ms
22:19:02.446  I/MeasureFps: Average frame time = 497.2 ms
22:19:04.349  I/MeasureFps: Average frame time = 342.8 ms
22:19:12.984  I/MeasureFps: Average frame time = 1715.0 ms
```

Comment: What is the advertisement interval of your BLE device(s)?

Comment: The first broadcast would take longer (wait until stable) to start, about 2 seconds.
Then it broadcasts every 100 ms.

Comment: If you enable the Bluetooth snoop log you can see in wireshark what scan parameters the phone is choosing. If the scan window equals the scan interval you should get no latency and all packets should be catched. Remember that since Android uses active scanning (sending scan requests in response to advertisement packets and waiting for scan responses), you'll probably not get all advertisement packets. And what is it you want to achieve? Can't you just stay connected and send data that way?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My app is to monitor status of many ble devices, by checking the advertisement data. The phone can't connect so many ble devices at the same time.